# .htaccess: Rewite rule to change to Semantic URL Struture

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I am trying to change the URL structure of a search filter using `.htaccess` from this:

`/tours/?tour-type=guided&tour-destination=europe&tour-type=guided&tour-duration=17%2B&tour-season=2020`

to this:

`/tours/guided/europe/guided/17/2020`

Obviously the search filter has many different options such as days, locations different types and the like, I know it's possible in `.htaccess` but its proving elusive to me.

Comment: "I know it's possible in `.htaccess`" - not if this is part of a WordPress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress it's better to use `add_rewite_rule` function. In example below I assume that tours is custom post type so `post_type=tours`. You can put there page id, category slug or whatever you want.
Note that with this rule if you want to send only tour-season you have to send something for rest of variables.

```
function tour_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^tours/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=tours&tour-type=$matches[1]&tour-destination=$matches[2]&tour-type=$matches[3]&tour-duration=$matches[4]&tour-season=$matches[5]', 'top' );    
}
add_action('init', 'tour_add_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```